# How to not make sed overlap the first argument which is replaced?

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to do something like below

```
sed -ie 's/Grp-0/Grp-19/g; s/Grp-1/Grp-20/g'
```

But what is happening is in first instance grp-19 replaces Grp-0 but In the second instance the part of Grp-1 to Grp-20.
There is replacement in all replaced values as well as what i had replaced to Grp-19. So all Grp-19 becomes Grp-209.

Any suggestions on what is the best way?

Comment: I edited the command , i just by mistake interchanged the value.while copy pasting just took the opposite one.

Comment: Note that your option `-ie` creates a backup of your file with `e` appended to the end of the file name.  The `-i` option is not something you should be using until you're sure your script does what you need it to do.

Comment: In this limited example, switching the order of the commands would solve it elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `Grp-N` entries do not appear at the end of a line, then you can use:

```
sed -e 's/Grp-0\([^0-9]\)/Grp-19\1/; s/Grp-1\([^0-9]\)/Grp-20\1/'
```

This looks for `Grp-0` followed by a non-digit and maps it to `Grp-19` followed by the non-digit.  Similarly for `Grp-1` followed by a non-digit, and so on.

Another option is to start a new cycle after a substitution occurs:

```
sed -e 's/Grp-0/Grp-19/; t; s/Grp-1/Grp-20/; t …'
```

The `t` command with no named label jumps to the end of the script if a `s///` command has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last `t` command.

With things sequenced in increasing order, you can still run into problems if you have enough of these mappings.  If you sequence the tests in reverse order, you don't run into problems — map `Grp-19` before you map `Grp-0` (with the `t` to skip).

However, you should aim to avoid writing out a systematic mapping longhand.  Tools like `awk` or Perl can do arithmetic, so when they find `Grp-NN`, they can substitute NN+19 for the original value.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ie 's/Grp-0/\n/g;s/Grp-1/Grp-20/g;s/\n/Grp-19/g' file
```

Replace the first string by a unique identifier (newline is unique as it is removed by sed itself before populating the pattern space), replace all occurrences of the second string and then replace all newlines by the replacement for the first string.